# Корректное отображение графики при рисовании

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте. Решил попрактиковаться cо Swing, Java. Создаю простой Пэйнт. Так вот, если быстро обновляется позиция мыши, то есть отрывки в нарисованном сегменте. В главном трэде читаю позицию мыши в mouseDragged, а в другом читаю из очереди и рисую в буфeр(BufferedImage). Какие техники можно использовать?

Рисует.

```
private class DrawThread extends Thread{
    public void run() {
        Point point;
        int bsize;
        Graphics buff = buffImage.getGraphics();//BufferedImage
        while (!closing) {
            try {
                if (!pointsList.isEmpty()) {
                    buff.setColor(colorPanel.getCurrentColor());
                    bsize = brushSizePanel.getBrushSize();
                    point = pointsList.poll();
                    buff.fillRect((int) point.getX(), 
                                  (int) point.getY(), 
                                       bsize, bsize);
                } else
                    drawPanel.repaint();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.getStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Сохраняет позиции.

```
 public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseMoved(e);
                if(instrumentPanel.getCurrInstrument()==1) {
                    try {
                        //pointsList: ArrayBlockingQueue<Point>
                        pointsList.put(new Point(e.getX(),e.getY()));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
 }
```

drawPanel.paint()

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(buffImage,0,0,null);
}
```

Comment: Сохранять позицию предыдущей точки и вместо fillRect вызывать drawLine с рисованием линии от предыдущей точки к текущей. Тогда вместо разрывов будет просто прямая линия.

Comment: Да, но нужно чтобы кисть была разного размера. 1,2,5 точек...

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BasicStroke.html

BasicStroke - там можно указывать толщину и другие параметры для графических примитивов.